# Is it possible to get the number of pages from a File?

Tags: flutter

Guys I'm using `file_picker` to get files from the device. I use `open_file` to display the file. Is there any way to get the number of pages from the file? I have already seen the possibility with .pdf, but I would like to get from .docs as well.

Comment: Does this work? [Number of pages of a word document with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12964580/7543069)

Comment: The short answer is... Yes, it is.

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα Do you know how?

Comment: Yes, I do. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702252/i-want-to-get-total-pages-count-from-pdf-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try Flutter FileReader
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader

A local file view widget,Support a variety of file types, such as Doc Eexcl PPT TXT and so on,Android is implemented by Tencent X5,iOS is implemented by WKWebView

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_filereader/flutter_filereader.dart';

class FileReaderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String filePath;

  FileReaderPage({Key: Key, this.filePath});

  @override
  _FileReaderPageState createState() => _FileReaderPageState();
}

class _FileReaderPageState extends State<FileReaderPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("doc"),
      ),
      body: FileReaderView(
        filePath: widget.filePath,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OR open_document

Opening pdf, xlsx, docs, ppt and zip files #
https://pub.dev/packages/open_document

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried them but couldn't find any implementation. Besides that ```flutter_filereader``` is crashing my app with its web view.